# Swipe down to refresh for list view not displaying list data

Tags: android, xml

I am getting data in my list view which i verified by giving Toasts but some where i guess in layout it is wrong when swipe down to refresh is done for list view,list is not displaying data.Below is my main layout file.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/text_json"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


     </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put SwipeRefreshLayout only for Listview

Comment: Thanks a lot .It worked.

Comment: I will put this in Answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use SwipeRefreshLayout only for List View i.e

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/text_json"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

     </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```